# Can't concatinate texture_features and resnet50_features

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensor, feature-extraction

I have extracted resnet features(array) and texture features(list) of my image dataset. My idea is to concatinating both of the features and then use the merged feature to fit the model.
Code snippet:

```
# Extract features from the dataset using ResNet50
resnet50_features = ResNet50.predict(X_test)
for category in categories:
    path = os.path.join(data_dir,category)
    # print(path)
    class_num = categories.index(category)

    for img in os.listdir(path):

            try:
                image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))[:,:,::-1]
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                gabor_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((21, 21), 8.0, 0, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
                filtered_image = cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_8UC3, gabor_kernel)
                texture_features.append(filtered_image)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

The Dimensions of resnet50_features (98, 7, 7, 2048), I converted texture_features from list to array and the dimension is (766, 224, 224)

I tried concatenating both, but it is giving an error. My question is: how do I merge these two, and how can I use them to classify? A simple code snippet would be great!